# I am little confused with innetText or createTextNode() work same which should be used

Tags: javascript, dom

> index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <h1 class="a">Heading</h1>
        <h1 class="a">Heading</h1>
        <h1 class="a">Heading</h1>
        <p id="poco">adadadadad</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <p class="one">bad</p>
        <p class="one">bad</p>
        <p class="one">bad</p>
    </div>

    <div id="col">
        <p>One</p>
        <p>Two</p>

    </div>
        

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> app.js

```
let sel = document.querySelector("p#poco");
let elm = document.createElement("h1");
elm.innerText = "pitcher";
console.log(elm);
sel.appendChild(elm)
```

I am able to do same thing with innerText so why should I use createTextNode() is there any preference or anything else;

it's give same result when I use createTextNode()

Comment: There is more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using innerText, it will erase all existing text inside your tag but when you are using createTextNode() and appendChild(), it will add new text at the end of the existing text.

Answer (score 1):

createTextNode is basically a function on the document object that creates a new text DOM node w/ text provided as the first argument. A node is returned and you have to then insert it into the DOM using appenchild.

innerText property of the HTMLElement interface represents the "rendered" text content of a node and its descendants. *(innerText is easily confused with Node.textContent, but there are important differences between the two. Basically, innerText is aware of the rendered appearance of text, while textContent is not.)*

---

[**Benchmark**](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/3618/0/createtextnode-vs-textcontent-vs-innertext-vs-innerhtml)

*User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36*

*Browser/OS: Chrome 91 on Windows*

```
textContent    3197203.0 Ops/sec

innerText       871249.1 Ops/sec

createTextNode  762514.5 Ops/sec

innerHTML       216747.5 Ops/sec
```